# Is it allowed to create an auction app on FB?

Tags: facebook, paypal, payment

I wonder if it is allowed to create and operate an app inside FB in which users can bid for products and pay with paypal. Does FB allow only free apps in which no real money involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any app that is free on facebook, most of them you can play without paying, but at some stage you will have to pay to continue or to get additional in game money or items. So yes, applications that handle payments are allowed.